# What is Mapreduce equivalent to top() function in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I am trying to find the equivalent solution to `top()` and `take()` functions in spark, for Mapreduce implementation. I want to extract the top k values, without saving the whole key, value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct equivalent. If you need to do something similar without having Spark, I generally use Pig

It requires at least two map reduce phases. One to process the data, then another to collect the data you actually want

In the mapper, you set null writable (or some, single valued key), then emit all values, forcing them to a single reducer.

In the reducer, you collect all values you want to sort or emit into a limited size collection. I recommend a TreeMap or Binary Heap, because they auto-sort. Then, you loop over the size of that collection for K values